# How can I import and plot a triangular mesh in R?

Tags: r, opengl, graphics, 3d, mesh

I would like to plot my model output in R

It is a triangular mesh in the format

```
x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 x3 y3 z3 value
```

Where each row represents a triangle, and I would like to plot these triangles with `value` as the scale.

```
mymesh <- structure(c(0.91, 0.45, 13.93, 14.26, 14.15, 14.36, 14.36, 14.61, 
    14.58, 14.87, 14.8, 15.13, 15.02, 15.39, 15.24, 15.65, 15.46, 
    15.9, 15.69, 16.16, 0, 0.79, 12.45, 12.64, 12.34, 12.46, 12.24, 
    12.38, 12.13, 12.3, 12.03, 12.22, 11.92, 12.13, 11.81, 12.04, 
    11.69, 11.94, 11.57, 11.84, 0, 0, 208.71, 208.69, 210.7, 210.68, 
    212.68, 212.66, 214.67, 214.65, 216.66, 216.63, 218.64, 218.61, 
    220.62, 220.59, 222.61, 222.57, 224.59, 224.56, 0.45, 1.5, 14.15, 
    14.15, 14.36, 14.36, 14.58, 14.58, 14.8, 14.8, 15.02, 15.02, 
    15.24, 15.24, 15.46, 15.46, 15.69, 15.69, 15.92, 15.92, 0.79, 
    0, 12.34, 12.34, 12.24, 12.24, 12.13, 12.13, 12.03, 12.03, 11.92, 
    11.92, 11.81, 11.81, 11.69, 11.69, 11.57, 11.57, 11.45, 11.45, 
    0, 131.83, 210.7, 210.7, 212.68, 212.68, 214.67, 214.67, 216.66, 
    216.66, 218.64, 218.64, 220.62, 220.62, 222.61, 222.61, 224.59, 
    224.59, 226.58, 226.58, 1.5, 0.75, 14.26, 14.36, 14.36, 14.61, 
    14.61, 14.87, 14.87, 15.13, 15.13, 15.39, 15.39, 15.65, 15.65, 
    15.9, 15.9, 16.16, 16.16, 16.42, 0, 1.3, 12.64, 12.46, 12.46, 
    12.38, 12.38, 12.3, 12.3, 12.22, 12.22, 12.13, 12.13, 12.04, 
    12.04, 11.94, 11.94, 11.84, 11.84, 11.74, 131.83, 131.83, 208.69, 
    210.68, 210.68, 212.66, 212.66, 214.65, 214.65, 216.63, 216.63, 
    218.61, 218.61, 220.59, 220.59, 222.57, 222.57, 224.56, 224.56, 
    226.54, 375.12, 399.8, 297.84, 497.63, 368.17, 1113.19, 979, 
    781.41, 1202.21, 1113.94, 1293.77, 1391.94, 1364.52, 1151.37, 
    1690.98, 913.63, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(20L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("x1", "y1", "z1", "x2", "y2", "z2", "x3", "y3", "z3", 
    "value")))
```

I have looked at the `rgl`, `plot3D`, and `misc3d` packages. However, these seem to be dealing with points rather than triangles (for example, the `rgl.points`, `rgl.linestrips`, and `rgl.triangles` functions all take `x,y,z` as inputs, rather than a triangle).

How can I use R to plot and color the triangles in this dataset?

Comment: Have you tried [`rgl::triangles3d`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/vignettes/rgl.html#primitive-shapes)? Its help page (`?triangles3d`) includes a nice example. It looks to me like (if it's what you're after) your only task will then be to reshape your data into the appropriately formatted 3-column matrix.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks for pointing that out. I had trouble finding documentation, and couldn't figure out how arguments x y z could be used on vertices of a triangle ... especially without some sort of identifier for the component points ... But apparently, triangle3d "takes each successive triple of points as the vertices of a triangle". And I also stumbled across the light3d function, which could also be a useful tool.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Isn't it what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generated a plot using the `shade3d` and `tmesh3d` functions from `rgl`.
It creates two separate bars. The different triangulars are coloured differently. Look at the plot below.

```
rgl.open()
i <- 1
vertices <- c(mymesh[i,1:3],1,mymesh[i,4:6],1,mymesh[i,7:9],1)
indices <- c( 1, 2, 3)
shade3d( tmesh3d(vertices,indices) , col=1)
bg3d(color = "white")
for(i in 2:20){
     vertices <- c(mymesh[i,1:3],1,mymesh[i,4:6],1,mymesh[i,7:9],1)
     indices <- c( 1, 2, 3)
     shade3d( tmesh3d(vertices,indices) , col= i)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `polygon()` function! :) It's awesome - you can draw any shape you want. Base R plotting is actually pretty sweet sometimes.

(wrong)

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to construct a 3D mesh. Is that possible?

Comment: Ah, just got that. My bad. Hmm. With polygon(), only if you project your coordinates yourself onto 2-D. http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/02/3d-plots-in-r.html won't work? Good luck